# having error when showing alertDialog in asyncTask that is called from service?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, android-context

I have a service that doing some work and at the end I execute my asynctask(its name is background).
In asyncTask,In onPostExecute() I want to show an alertDialog.
but when i debug my app, error accures in my service at the line that i execute my asyncTask.  this line:

`backGround=new BackGround(context);
 backGround.execute(String.valueOf(send_json))`

I know that the error accures because  of the context that i send to asyncTask.
I apply getApplicationContext(); & getBaseContext();& service's context,too; but error doesn't disapear.
I apply this code in the mainActivity with its context and no error occures,so I am sure this error is because of the context that i send it from my service to asyncTask's constructor.

So, what can I do?
I appreciate any help.

Edited:this is the error.

```
09-08 18:39:35.253 20251-20813/ir.blog.trafik E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
                                                                          at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:111)
                                                                          at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
                                                                          at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:931)
                                                                          at ir.blog.trafik.BackGround.onPreExecute(BackGround.java:88)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
                                                                          at ir.blog.trafik.locationService.json_maker(locationService.java:538)
                                                                          at ir.blog.trafik.locationService$1.run(locationService.java:588)
                                                                          at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

this is my asyncTask class:

```
public class BackGround   extends AsyncTask < String , Void , String > {
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
public BackGround(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params){
String location_url ="http://192.168.1.90/server_connection.php";
    try{
        URL url1=new URL(location_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =          (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream stream_upload=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter buffer_writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream_upload,"UTF-8"));
        // String PostData= URLEncoder.encode()

        buffer_writer.write(String.valueOf(params));


        buffer_writer.flush();
        buffer_writer.close();
        stream_upload.close();





        InputStream stream_dawnload=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferreader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream_dawnload,"iso-8859-1"));
        String result="";
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;}
        bufferreader.close();
        stream_upload.flush();
        stream_dawnload.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return result;



    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login status");
}

 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
   alertDialog.show();
}
```

this is my service's code:

```
 public class locationService extends Service{Context context;BackGround backGround ;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
      context =this;
     }

 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

Toast.makeText(context,"service started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    doSomeThingRepeatedly(context);


    return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;



}
```

and this is my doSomeThingReapetedly() method that i called it in onStartcommand()

```
 private  void doSomeThingRepeatedly(final Context context) {
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
......
      backGround=new BackGround(context);
    backGround.execute(String.valueOf(send_json));
}


    }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
```

After adding "Pravin Divraniya's" solution, it works fine but an error occurs in asyncTask after debuging onPostExecute() and intering to doInBackground(), that error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:804)
                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:288)
                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
                                                                          at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
                                                                          at ir.blog.trafik.BackGround.onPostExecute(BackGround.java:103)
                                                                          at ir.blog.trafik.BackGround.onPostExecute(BackGround.java:22)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the error message ??

Comment: Also post your code.

Comment: @thunder413 I edited,and I added my error massage.

Comment: @PravinDivraniya which code?asyncTask?

Comment: Yes, also the line in which you are getting error.

Comment: @PravinDivraniya  I added my code,too.

Comment: Are you using Service or IntentService?

Comment: @PravinDivraniyaI used service

Comment: Paste code from where you are calling backGround.execute(String.valueOf(send_json)).

Comment: @PravinDivraniya I did,plz check,thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [AsynkTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation (Read **Threading rules** section)

1. The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
2. The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
3. execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
4. Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
5. The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)

If you want to do repeated operation you can do it using `Handler`. Create Handler in `onStartCommand` (so, from the UI thread). Then use that Handler to trigger `AsyncTask`.

```
    private Handler mHandler = null;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
//Here 1000 is delayMillis,  you can set your delay here.
    }
```

create Runnable class instance inside your service class and call AsyncTask from there.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            backGround=new BackGround(context);
            backGround.execute(String.valueOf(send_json));
        }
    };
```

If you wish to stop repeted calls to runnable, simply call `mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);`

**Update :-**
We cant show normal Alert dialog with service context so below is two possible solutions.

*Solution 1 :-*

We can show dialog from service only if it is a system alert dialog. So, set TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT window layout parameter to Dialog as follows:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

But, it needs SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. So, don't forget to add this permissin in Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

*Solution 2 :-*

Try to start an Activity and set the Activity's Theme to Theme.Dialog.
There is a demo in `ApiDemo` Project. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme) link on how to apply theme to an activity or application.

**Just for Information**

1. A `Service` runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify in manifest otherwise). `IntentService` runs on worker thread(non UIThread).
2. You can call `mHandler.postDelayed` from any thread, because once we are create handler instance it is associated with the Thread in which it create. in our case it is UIThread as we are creating it in `onStartCommand` method.

Feel free to ask any query.

Hope this will help you and clear your doubts.

Comment: thank u, it works like a charm :). something important is  "import android.os.Handler",but after adding this code an error occures:

Comment: I add it to my question plz check it ,THANK U.

Comment: Also i'm thankful for additional information that you added,They are so useful .

Comment: after updating your answer i applied it and it worked,but now app just works for once and in debug window writes: app is running and in logCat it says:I/Choreographer: Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. why it occures?what is the solution now?can u help?plz.

Comment: You might be doing some heavy operation(Network or some heavy calculations etc..) in your main UI thread that's why this warning comes.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating dialog inside `doInBackground()` which runs in worker thread, try creating it either in `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute` depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error come from the fact that you want to launch an ui from a service witch is not running on the main thread and Service does not have an implementation for runOnUiThread the work arround is to use a LocalBroadcastManager and a broadcastreceiver on any activity and open the dialog from the activity below a sample example

In your service

```
Intent intent = new Intent("showDialog");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In any activity on frgament

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("showDialog")) {
            // Show your dialog here
        }
    }
};
```

And dont forget to register the receiver

```
// Register receiver onStart/onCreate
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("showDialog"));
    // Unregister onDestroy
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Comment: Yes, I havea service that has a function that in it I have a timer,And as I know when a timerTask is declared , a new thread is prepared; and I use my code :           backGround=new BackGround(context);
 backGround.execute(String.valueOf(send_json))     in the timerTask...But I didn't understand your answer where u said :"In any activity on frgament",where i should add this code u said?

Comment: I edited my question and i add my service class.plz check it,thank u.